# American TV channel/network that aired old anime, in the 2000s that had an X in the Logo

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime

The network/channel had *Digimon* on it and a show very similar to it, this was on about 10 years ago and I don't believe is currently on air. It had a logo of an X or something, sorry that's all I remember.

Comment: Is the other show Pokemon?

Comment: I think this question is too broad. [Many networks have carried *Digimon* over the years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon#Distribution_and_localization)

Comment: I don't think so?

Comment: It definitely feels like it. We try to ask questions that help anyone that might come to the site. That being said, if two people posted different networks how would you pick between them? How would you make sure it was still useful to anyone else that came to the site? If you wanted the first, anyone can check and see that is correct. That would be a better question. Likewise if you narrowed down to a date and location it *might* be workable. It's not too late to edit and try to get it reopened.

Comment: What country were you in 10 years ago that you saw a channel with an X in the logo, and that aired Digimon? Was it a 24 hour network, or was it just an anime/cartoon block that they aired on certain days/times (like Toonami or Adult Swim)?

Comment: USA boy America whatever

Comment: Also I cant think of the name but if i see it I think i will remember, Its a good question to me

Comment: Just seen your edit, its much better. For what its worth It's probably jetix, in the uk who rerun lots of old anime and cartoons.

Comment: @Pureferret Yup. Jetix [aired Digimon in the US 10 years ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Jetix). Jetix became Disney XD. It fits all of the requirements.

Comment: Yes it is jetix thks

Comment: I got it guys thks bro :)

Comment: http://i.ytimg.com/vi/D9lbrninN6Y/hqdefault.jpg

Answer (score 2):

My initial guess is [Jetix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Jetix#Jetix_US).

Here's the current logo:

[image: Current Jetix Logo]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Jetix.png))</sub>

Credit goes to phantom42 for confirming my guess.

Oh and for what it's worth the channel used to be called Fox Kids in the 90s. And has been replaced by DisneyXD.

Comment: Something funky is going on with the years/brands.  Fox Kids became the [FoxBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4Kids_TV#History), which lasted until 2005, but Jetix started in 2004 and claims to be the successor to Fox Kids?

Comment: @Izkata FoxBox was aired on the actual Fox network. Jetix began airing on what was the Toon Disney channel at the time. The channel later went on to become Disney XD.

Answer (score 1):

[Fox Kids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_Kids) was the first network/programming block to air [Digimon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon#Digimon_Adventure) in the US (1999-2002, the first 3 seasons), and had a prominent `X` in the logo:

[image: Fox Kids]